# Can we say "to have forgotten" in this case?

Tags: present-perfect

> Would it be possible for you to have forgotten that you owe 30 pounds?

I think this is good but not sure that "to have forgotten" is correct here. At the time of writing I am not sure if you still have forgotten it or not so "to have forgotten" sounds good .

Comment: It's fine, and a normal way of expressing the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking casually, your sentence is fine. Everyone will understand it, but grammatically, it's not perfect.

"Would it be possible" indicates an unreal situation, but the perfect grammar indicates a real one. The same sentence written with a simple infinitive would have the same meaning, and be consistently an unreal, hypothetical situation:

> Would it be possible for you **to forget** that you owe 30 pounds?

Or to make the whole thing real:

> **Is** it possible for you to have forgotten that you owe 30 pounds?

Comment: I can imagine, as a Brit, 'would it be possible...' being used sarcastically.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible for you to have forgotten that you owe 30 pounds?

Yes, many people try to forget their debts.

Are you asking whether the sentence “Would it be possible for you to have forgotten that you owe 30 pounds?” is grammatically correct — it is — or whether it is idiomatic?

If the context is, as I surmise, the speaker is trying to gently prompt the other person to pay the debt, I think a more common phrase would be “*Is* it possible...” — suggesting the debtor is forgetful, but not a deadbeat.